# Adding integer values as contents of an array,iphone

Tags: iphone, arrays, integer

I need to store some integer values as the contents of an array. But when i try to do so, it throws a warning,
passing argument 1 of 'addObject' makes pointer from integer without a cast.
And obviously the value is not stored in the array.
Here's thecode.

```
NSUInteger i;
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
 [array addObject:i];}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NSArray`-s cannot store non-`id` objects. You have to box it into an `NSNumber`:

```
NSUInteger i;
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
   [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:i]];
}
```

or use a `CFArray` with custom callbacks (but you sacrifice readability for performance), or use `std::vector<NSUInteger>` (but you need to use Objective-C++).

Comment: @Nithin: You can get an `NSUInteger` from an `NSNumber` with `-unsignedIntegerValue`.

Comment: pls give an example for that.

Comment: NSUInteger anInt = [[array objectAtIndex:0] unsignedIntegerValue];